# Некорректно работает new Date

Tags: javascript, дата, new

Почему дата возвращает 2021-11-18, а не 2021-11-19?

```js
const testData = new Date('Fri Nov 19 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)').toISOString().slice(0, 10);
console.log(testData);
```

Comment: Подождите ещё часика два, и всё будет норм ;-) Как Вы думаете, для чего придумали [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами все отрезали.

```js
const testData = new Date('Fri Nov 19 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)');
console.log(testData.toLocaleString());
console.log(testData.toISOString());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Странно, конечно, надо изучить)